# How to login to an external website after drupal-login?

Tags: 8, redirection

I would like know how I can login my user to an external website after drupal-login please ?

I use :

```
    $xenAPI = new XenAPI('http://xen.dev/api.php', 'MY_API_KEY', 'MY_API_KEYSALT'); 
    $xenAPI->login('Kyna', 'secret_password', 'http://theming.dev');
```

The login work on all page when I use HOOK_user_load(), but if I use HOOK_user_login(), don't work. I don't have an error, but ->login() create a redirection with an header and I think drupal-login overwrite my header on external script or create a redirection before my script.

Comment: Yes, the login form has a redirection. See \Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::submitForm() so you need to remove that redirection with $this->getRequest()->query->remove('destination')

Comment: @IvanJaros that's an answer, please post it so.

Comment: @IvanJaros Could you write that as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the login form has a redirection(see the `\Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::submitForm()`), so you need to remove that redirection with `$this->getRequest()->query->remove('destination')`.